# Separating data in a string into different variables

Tags: python, python-3.x

Using Python 3.

I would like to parse a set of strings which are of the same format. One example I have is a list of books in the format:

*title (year), author*

e.g.
"The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy (1979), Douglas Adams"

I'd like to extract the book's title, year and author from these strings using something elegant.

Something like:

```py
book = "The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy (1979), Douglas Adams"
data = parsing_function(book, format)
```

where:

- `format` is some input that describes the format of the
  input string. A coded way of saying "author first, then the year in the brackets, then the author after the comma". Something like `format = '{title} ({year}), {author}'`
- `data` is the extracted title, year, etc. This could be a list or even better a dictionary.

This is inspired by the way Pandas parses date/time strings into datetime variables - see `pandas.to_datetime` [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html).
A `format` variable is passed in to the function to show how the date/time is represented, like:

```
pandas.to_datetime('13000101', format='%Y%m%d', errors='ignore')
 >>> datetime.datetime(1300, 1, 1, 0, 0)
```

Is there a similar method of separating data in a string into different variables?

I can see a way to write a function for this specific case (e.g. using `str.split()` on the brackets/comma and separating that way), but I'm looking for a generic function that can be used on strings in any consistent format.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) matching your structured string:

```
import re

book = "The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy (1979), Douglas Adams"

m = re.match(r'(.+) \((.+)\), (.+)', book)
title, year, author = m.groups()
```

You can name the capturing groups (the stuff between unescaped parentheses `"(...)"`) to make things more explicit.

```
m = re.match(r'(?P<title>.+) \((?P<year>.+)\), (?P<author>.+)', book)
m.group("title")
# "The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy"
m.group("year")
# '1979'
m.group("author")
# 'Douglas Adams'
```

Comment: If its getting more complex, something like a  word tokenization package could be a good way too. Something that is used in natural language processing.

Comment: I am not sure that you would gain much. Regexes are quite powerful in parsing strings of consistent patterns. Unless you are venturing into context-sensitive territory (where simple tokenization won't be enough, but serious NLP parsing algorithms are required) this should be fine. And it comes with the standard library.

Comment: Thanks @schwobaseggl, exactly what I was looking for